# Command php artisan migrate fails to run all migrations with error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table

Tags: mysql, laravel, migrate

Starting fresh when I run `php artisan migrate` it works and creates a number of tables until it reaches migrations which contain instructions to create an index.

The error content always starts with: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table"

The code for one of the migrations which caused this error is below:

```
        Schema::create('item_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_general_ci';

            $table->id();

            $table->bigInteger('item_id', false, true);
            $table->bigInteger('section_element_id', false, true);
            $table->text('content');
            $table->enum('is_active', DefaultOption::justKeys())->default(DefaultOption::YES->value);

            $table->dateTime('created_at');
            $table->bigInteger('created_by',false, true)->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('updated_at')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('updated_by',false, true)->nullable();

            $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('item')->onUpdate('no action')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('section_element_id')->references('id')->on('section_element')->onUpdate('no action')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->index(['item_id', 'is_active']); //if I remove this line the migration runs OK
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('no action')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('no action')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```

If I comment the following line: `$table->index(['item_id', 'is_active']);` the migration runs just fine.

If I run this command `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2023_08_07_000006_item_data_create.php --pretend` I can get the actual SQL query executed:

```
create table `item_data` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `item_id` bigint unsigned not null, `section_element_id` bigint unsigned not null, `content` text not null, `is_active` enum('yes', 'no') not null default 'yes', `created_at` datetime not null, `created_by` bigint unsigned null, `updated_at` datetime null, `updated_by` bigint unsigned null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_general_ci' engine = InnoDB;
alter table `item_data` add constraint `item_data_item_id_foreign` foreign key (`item_id`) references `item` (`id`) on delete cascade on update no action;
alter table `item_data` add constraint `item_data_section_element_id_foreign` foreign key (`section_element_id`) references `section_element` (`id`) on delete cascade on update no action;
alter table `item_data` add index `item_data_item_id_is_active_index`(`item_id`, `is_active`);
alter table `item_data` add constraint `item_data_created_by_foreign` foreign key (`created_by`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null on update no action;
alter table `item_data` add constraint `item_data_updated_by_foreign` foreign key (`updated_by`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set null on update no action;
```

When I try to run it on the database it fails again at the part with

```
alter table `item_data` add index `item_data_item_id_is_active_index`(`item_id`, `is_active`);
```

If I comment on this the table is created just fine and after that, I can run:

```
// alter table `item_data` add index `item_data_item_id_is_active_index`(`item_id`, `is_active`);
```

...with no errors.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it make any difference to move the `index` call before the `foreign` definitions?

Comment: check that your mysql server is on or port is block or not

Comment: try $table->index(['item_id', 'is_active']); putting this at the end or in new cshema::table migration.

Comment: So @PaulT. suggestion did actually fix the issue.

Comment: And I think I understand the root of the problem. When creating a foreign key, there is also an index added, and when adding the index-specific command it affects the already set index, and MySQL prefers to say "connection lost". Bottom line first index then constraints in migrations

Comment: You are using very odd syntax here, not sure how you came up with it. For foreign keys, all you need is e.g. `$table->foreignId('item_id')->constrained();`. And you don't create timestamp columns manually, just use `$table->timestamps()`. Read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations) before setting out on these journeys.

Comment: @miken32 I want datetimes not timestamps and $table->foreign is in the documentation.